# Elegant solution about class and referencing

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.5

I've recently started using classes in my programs and I've got 2 problems/questions.
Following the question I've pasted not the whole code, but only the part about which I need advise about.

1)the only way I have found to access to the value the user will input in my GUI's entry widget is to declare the list `ac` global, so I can later append the various entry widget for further reference. I tried it in my `printer` function and it worked. I was just wondering if there is another way to manage the problem because using a `global` variable, according to what I read on the net, is not the very best idea.

2)I've got some problem with doing the same thing with the optionwidget. I can't find a way to get the data because of variable referencing problems. Assuming that I'm managing this thing the best way an apprentice of Python could, how can I do that?

If I wasn't clear, please let me know. I'm not a native English speaker and I still have to get confidence with the language.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk ()
root.title("GENERATOR")
root.geometry("300x300")


class entryandlabel:


    global ac
    ac=[]



    def printer():
    #as an example
       print(ac[2].get())



    def createentry(lista):

    #entry widget creation

        i=1
        for a in lista:
            entry = Entry (root)
            entry.grid(row=i, column=1, sticky = W)
            ac.append(entry)
            i+=1


    def createoption(lista, c):

    #option widget creation

        a = StringVar(root)
        a.set("Selezionare")
        b = OptionMenu(*(root, a) + tuple(lista))
        b.grid(row=c, column=1)
```

Comment: Why do you have the `entryandlabel` class at all? You have no instance state, and the functions in the class body make no sense as methods.

Comment: attach your widgets and lists to the object itself. You should define an `__init__` method which creates the `ac` variable (as `self.ac = []`). You will need to read some tutorials on python classes to understand the need for a `self` argument to each 'instance method' of a python class.